# must have properties for core-site hdfs-site mapred-site and yarn-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Can anyone please let me know the must have properties for Core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml without which hadoop can not start?

Answer (score 1):

Below settings is for Hadoop 2.x.x for Standalone and Pseudo node setup.

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

also refer apache hadoop documentation for [single node setup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Hadoop:_Setting_up_a_Single_Node_Cluster.)