# How to run pySpark on Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, pyspark

I am just new in Hadoop world.
I am going to install a standalone version of Hadoop on my PC to save files on HDFS (of course 1 node) and then run pySpark to read files from HDFS and process them. I have no clue how can I put these pieces next together. 
Can anyone please give me a crystal clear order of components that I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using windows PC then you have to install VM player or
   Oracle virtual box then

   1.a. install any of linux distribution e.g. centos, rhel, ubuntu etc in your VM

   1.b. install JAVA in your VM

   1.c follow from step 2.b onwards
2. If you are using Linux machine then

   2a. install JAVA
   2b download stable version of [apache hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html)

   2.c then extract tar file in /usr/your/directory

   2.d make configurations in your ~/.bash_profile for your hadoop path 
   e.g.`export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`

   2.e make configurations in core-site.xml hdfs-site.xml mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml by following this [must have properties for core-site hdfs-site mapred-site and yarn-site.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357226/must-have-properties-for-core-site-hdfs-site-mapred-site-and-yarn-site-xml/41357552#41357552)

   2.f Format your name node and then start rest daemons

**NOTE: follow steps given in for installing [single node cluster](http://www.tecmint.com/install-configure-apache-hadoop-centos-7/) OR [APACHE Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Hadoop:_Setting_up_a_Single_Node_Cluster.)**

3. after installing and configuring hadoop in your PC

   3.a download [Apache spark](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

   3.b extract tar file and follow same instructions like exporting path in bash_profile file

   3.c start spark shell or pyspark shell

**NOTE: follow steps for [installing spark](https://www.dezyre.com/apache-spark-tutorial/apache-spark-installation-tutorial)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 10 Pro then you can install Ubuntu WSL 20.04(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps) then install Hadoop(https://dev.to/samujjwaal/hadoop-installation-on-windows-10-using-wsl-2ck1)
In this moment have two parts: one management for hdfs files and one management for applications.
So you can use the hadoop management for hdfs files to store/host any massive file which can copy condensed and then can be uncompressed in hadoop-drive-zone.
And then can install python(pySpark) or java or other language to create one app which will manage with the hadoop apps management.
The hadoop appication(let say pySpark) will can access any massive file stored into hadoop-drive-zone.
For installing the Apache Spark as alternative you can proceed like in this tutorial:
https://dev.to/awwsmm/installing-and-running-hadoop-and-spark-on-ubuntu-18-393h
or
https://kontext.tech/column/spark/311/apache-spark-243-installation-on-windows-10-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Remark: see that the above tutorial install the Hadoop 3.3.0 version(try it with ubuntu command: $ hadoop version) and in Spark installing tutorials must to choice/use adequate Spark version!